# How to use archiveDir with Web Deploy 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, backup, publish, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am currenlty using Web Deploy 3 with Automatic Backup. Yesterday, backup failed with error message 'ERROR_PACKAGE_TOO_LARGE'.

as per [MSDN](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_PACKAGE_TOO_LARGE)

> Resolution - Use the archiveDir provider when creating a package instead. Currently there is no solution for this limit with respect to automatic backups.

Now archiveDir works fine on command line

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Site" -dest:archivedir=c:\archive
```

I am pretty new to Web Deploy, can someone please help me to automate this with Web Deploy using VS2013? I don't want to login to server to manually back up my site and then come back to VS to publish. Is there any setting in .pubxml(Publish Profile) to achieve it?

Thanks